# 'Logical file name "MyDB" is already in use' Even though the database doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, tempdb, datafile

I recently was given a SAN with a couple of RAID arrays to apply to my database server to increase performance. I have (and will only ever have) one user database called `DDAS`, in addition to the system databases that install along with SQL Server.

My intent was to have `DDAS` pointing to its own drive, `tempdb` pointing to its own drive and transaction logs pointing to their own drive. The user account running SQL Server has Full Control access to all the drives, I made sure of it before doing anything.

I successfully moved `tempdb` using the following SQL statements:

```
ALTER DATABASE [tempdb] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'tempdev', FILENAME = N'F:\tempdb.mdf')
ALTER DATABASE [tempdb] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'templog', FILENAME = N'F:\templog.ldf')
```

I restarted SQL Server, voila, `tempdb` is relocated (can I safely delete the old `tempdb` files from their original location? Maybe that's another question...)

Now, because `DDAS` is still in development, I was able to delete all data from all the tables before doing anything to move it to its own drive. So now the file is ~5MB in size. I perform the same statements using the `DDAS` files:

```
ALTER DATABASE [DDAS] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'DDAS', FILENAME = N'E:\DDAS.mdf')
ALTER DATABASE [tempdb] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'DDAS_log', FILENAME = N'G:\DDAS_log.ldf')
```

I restart SQL Server and it doesn't work... I get `DDAS (Recovery Pending)` on the database in Management Studio indefinitely. I deleted the database completely because I have a script that will create all the objects etc... intending to just try to re-create it on the drive it is supposed to be on. I attempted to create the database with the following statement:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'DDAS')
BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE [DDAS]
    CONTAINMENT = NONE
    ON  PRIMARY 
        ( NAME = N'DDAS', FILENAME = N'E:\DDAS.mdf' , SIZE = 1024000KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024000KB  ) 
    LOG ON      
        ( NAME = N'DDAS', FILENAME = N'G:\DDAS_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
    END
GO
```

but I get this error now:

[image: what]

I used this query to list file names being used by SQL Server:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS DatabaseName, 
       name AS LogicalFileName, 
       physical_name AS PhysicalFileName 
FROM sys.master_files AS mf
```

and got this result:

[image: result]

How is this possible? I tried restarting SQL Server a number of times to no avail. I also checked that the original file on the `C:\` drive that `DDAS` was using has been deleted, as well as its transaction log. There's no trace of `DDAS` anywhere other than this error message. I also have no open connections to `DDAS` that might have somehow lingered through all of those restarts.

If it matters: SQL Server Enterprise 2014 x64

Comment: Also, please don't make your growth a percentage... Make it a MB value that makes sense.  If you have a drive dedicated to tempdb, which is a good thing, you should probably create tempdb with 8 files sized to almost entirely fill the drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i am able to figure out correctly from below query

```
ALTER DATABASE [tempdb] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'DDAS_log', FILENAME = N'G:\DDAS_log.ldf')
```

I believe `tempdb` to be `[DDAS]` here..

Also, in the `CREATE DATABASE` Query

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'DDAS')
BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE [DDAS]
    CONTAINMENT = NONE
    ON  PRIMARY 
        ( NAME = N'DDAS', FILENAME = N'E:\DDAS.mdf' , SIZE = 1024000KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024000KB  ) 
    LOG ON      
        ( NAME = N'DDAS', FILENAME = N'G:\DDAS_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
    END
GO
```

Above the logical file name of log file seems wrong, instead of LOG ON
            ( **NAME = N'DDAS'**....) it should have been NAME = N'**DDAS_log**'..

For more info please refer [CREATE DATABASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx)